# How to randomize lowest bits in a 64 bit pattern

Tags: c, random, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am interested in learning more about the concepts behind bit shifting and the manipulation of randomly generated bits. Below is some code that prints 20 random 64 bit patterns. "rand_bits" uses the C standard rand() to return a 64 bit pattern with all zeros except for the lowest bits, which are randomized. The number of low randomized bits is provided by the only parameter to the function.

```
   const int LINE_CNT = 20;

    void print_bin(uint64_t num, unsigned int bit_cnt);

    uint64_t rand_bits(unsigned int bit_cnt);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int i;

        srand(time(NULL));
        for(i = 0; i < LINE_CNT; i++) {
            uint64_t val64 = rand_bits(64);
            print_bin(val64, 64);
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }


    void print_bin(uint64_t num, unsigned int bit_cnt) {

        int top_bit_cnt;

        if(bit_cnt <= 0) return;
        if(bit_cnt > 64) bit_cnt = 64;

        top_bit_cnt = 64;
        while(top_bit_cnt > bit_cnt) {
            top_bit_cnt--;
            printf(" ");
        }

        while(bit_cnt > 0) {
            bit_cnt--;
            printf("%d", (num & ((uint64_t)1 << bit_cnt)) != 0);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return;
    }


    /*
     * Name: rand_bits
     * Function: Returns a 64 bit pattern with all zeros except for the
     *           lowest requested bits, which are randomized.  
     * Parameter, "bit_cnt":  How many of the lowest bits, including the
     *           lowest order bit (bit 0) to be randomized
     * Return: A 64 bit pattern with the low bit_cnt bits randomized.
     */
    uint64_t rand_bits(unsigned int bit_cnt) {


        printf("int bit_cnt:", bit_cnt);
        uint64_t result = rand();
        uint64_t result_1 = result>>5;
// uint64_t result_1 = result>>7;

//return result;
        return result_1;

    }
```

For example, if the function is called with 24 as the argument value, it might return a
64 bit pattern, such as:

```
0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_​1101_0110_0101_1110_0111_1100
```

Currently the function rand_bits may show more than 15 random bits coming from the rand() function, but this is by NO means guaranteed.

I thought that to get the 40 bits like in the example I could right shift the bits, but that does not seem to be the concept. Does this require a bit mask of the higher order bits or a mod calculation on the random number generator?

Any suggestions of how to return a bit pattern of all zeros with its lowest bits (bit_cnt) randomized?

UPDATE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

const int LINE_CNT = 20;

uint64_t rand_bits( unsigned number_of_bits ){

    uint64_t r = 0;
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i <= number_of_bits / 15; i++ ){
         r = (r << 15) | (rand() & 0x7fff ) ;
    }

    return r & ~(~0ull << number_of_bits) ;
}

void print_bin(uint64_t num, unsigned int bit_cnt) {

        int top_bit_cnt;

        if(bit_cnt <= 0) return;
        if(bit_cnt > 64) bit_cnt = 64;

        top_bit_cnt = 64;
        while(top_bit_cnt > bit_cnt) {
            top_bit_cnt--;
            printf(" ");
        }

        while(bit_cnt > 0) {
            bit_cnt--;
            printf("%d", (num & ((uint64_t)1 << bit_cnt)) != 0);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return;
    }


int main(void) {
int i;
/*      for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            print_bin(rand_bits(i),64);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
*/

        //I want to keep the code like this, but have the output shown in          //the links.
        srand(time(NULL));
        for(i = 0; i < LINE_CNT; i++) {
                uint64_t val64 = rand_bits(64);
                print_bin(val64, 64);
        }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I keep the code in main the way I had it originally, the output is all 0s. Any suggestions of how I can keep my code the way it was in main originally and produce exactly 20 lines of 64 bits with the lowest bits randomized?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `rand(2^(bit_cnt+1));`?

Comment: Notice `rand()` returns an integer in the `[0, RAND_MAX]` range.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError uint64_t result =rand(2^(bit_cnt+1));
Too many arguments to the function rand

Comment: @black So do I perform a rand function on that range? Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: @Justin_Finland: That was pseudo-code. Making it work is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

```
uint64_t rand_bits(unsigned int number_of_bits) 
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < number_of_bits/15 ; i++ )
    {
         r = (r<<15)|(rand()&32767u);
    }
    int remainder = number_of_bits-i*15;
    r = (r<<remainder)|(rand()&~(~0ull<<remainder));
    return r;
}
```

Since `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to provide 15 bits, there's no point doing 1 bit a time.

Comment: All bits are random and not just the lowest bits.

Comment: @user3528438 : I used a similar approach and Justin insists that does not work either - I am guessing operator error - it clearly works.

Comment: That code works located at the link you provided works, yes. However, I want to only modify the function rand_bits. The code at the link also modifies main. When I keep the code the way I have it in main, the program does not work properly and prints out all 0s. I will edit and explain. Thank you.

Comment: @Justin_Finland you are setting `bit_cnt` to always 64 and the answer you picked only works between [0, 63] (left shift in the final step overflows at 64). If I understand it correctly you need to change `bit_cnt` in the loop from `64` to `i`. https://ideone.com/k7LxCR

Comment: In which loop? The loop in main? If so then the loop states that i<i which is not possible. Please explain.

Comment: @Justin_Finland         for(i = 0; i < LINE_CNT; i++) {
                uint64_t val64 = rand_bits(`i`);
                print_bin(val64, 64);
        }

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` generates an `int` in the range `[0 ...RAND_MAX]`.  `RAND_MAX` is at least `32767` and certainly is 1 less than a power of 2.

So efficiently loop a few times until we have `bit_cnt` random bits.  This trick is to minimize the loop count by taking advantage that `RAND_MAX` is likely greater than `32767`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// Valid for 0 <= bit_cnt <= uintmax_t bit wdith
uintmax_t randomized_lowest_bits(unsigned bit_cnt) {
  // Create mask, same as maximum return value
  uintmax_t mask = 1;
  if (bit_cnt >= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uintmax_t)) {
    mask = -1;
  } else {
    mask = (mask << bit_cnt) - 1;
  }
  uintmax_t limit = mask;
  uintmax_t x = 0;

  while (limit) {
    // x *= (RAND_MAX +1)
    // Done as below to prevent numeric overflow of `RAND_MAX + 1u` on rare machines.
    // Let the compiler optimize it, likely into a fixed count left shift
#if RAND_MAX == INT_MAX
    x = x * (RAND_MAX / 2 + 1) * 2;
#else
    x *= RAND_MAX + 1;
#endif

    // Bring in more bits
    x += rand();

    // Carefully divide by RAND_MAX + 1 with overflow safe guards
    // Again, let the compiler optimize the code, likely into a fixed count right shift
#if RAND_MAX == INT_MAX
    limit = (limit / (RAND_MAX / 2 + 1)) / 2;
#else
    limit /= RAND_MAX + 1;
#endif
  }
  return x & mask;
}

void testR(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 64; i++) {
    printf("%jX\n", randomized_lowest_bits(i));
  }
}
```

Output

```
0
1
3
...
1192962917E96171
24833D39561F3B29
C3EC4ED846755A5B
```

Comment: Undeclared cnt and CHAR_BIT. Is cnt actually bit_cnt? Is CHAR_BIT the value of 8? Also, overflow warning for  x *= RAND_MAX + 1; and limit /= RAND_MAX + 1;.

Comment: Fixed cnt to be bit_cnt and CHAR_BIT to be 8. Ignored the overflow warnings. All of the bits are randomized, and not just the lowest bits. But, the first three 64 bit patterns are unique, and then the fourth bit pattern is the first so the patterns are not random, and everything is randomized.

Comment: @Justin_Finland Code corrections applied.  Errantly posted previous version.  `CHAR_BIT` comes from `stdlib.h` and is often 8.  `x *= RAND_MAX + 1` absolutely should not have caused a warning unless `#if RAND_MAX == INT_MAX` was removed.  Unclear how you  determined "All of the bits are randomized".  Posted a test driver function that had acceptable results.

Comment: Recipient of the consistent over-achiever award. Another good approach.

Comment: I determined that all of the bits are randomized because I am looking for something like this: 0000000000000000000000000000110011000100110011001010 where the lowest bits are ones and zeros while the higher order bits are only zeros of only the 64 bit values.

Comment: @Justin_Finland Your comment express what you wanted, but did not express what you saw.  `randomized_lowest_bits(24)` does return a integer with high order bits 0 and lower 24 randomized.  How is that not meeting your goal?

Comment: isn't `(unsigned int)RAND_MAX + 1` better than comparing with INT_MAX?

Comment: @basin Unclear on the context of your question.  Recall that type casting in `#` preprocessor math is not effective and that `(unsigned int)RAND_MAX + 1` _may_ be 0 (on rare platforms) in code.

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating a sufficient number of 15 bit random sequences, then masking the unwanted bits when `number_of_bits` is not an exact multiple of 15:

```
uint64_t rand_bits( int number_of_bits ) 
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i <= number_of_bits / 15; i++ )
    {
         r = (r << 15) | (rand() & 0x7fff ) ;
    }

    return r & ((number_of_bits >= 64) ? ~0ull : 
                                         ~(~0ull << number_of_bits) ) ;
}
```

Comment: Changed number_of_bits to unsigned int for consistency. All of the output values of the 64 bits are 0s.

Comment: @Justin_Finland : Are you saying that it does not work?  I beg to differ; see test code at https://ideone.com/32kCEs, or the same using your print_bin implementation - https://ideone.com/V5XNJo.  The use of `int` was quite deliberate, but makes no difference in this case.

Comment: That code works located at the link you provided works, yes. However, I want to only modify the function rand_bits. The code at the link also modifies main. When I keep the code the way I have it in main, the program does not work properly and prints out all 0s. I will edit and explain. Thank you.

Comment: This code has a problem that left shift 64 bits is UB. What usually happens is it would wrap back to 0 so the `rand_bits(64)` always returns 0; In OP's test code he is only testing `rand_bits(64)`;

Comment: @user3528438 : subtle but true - fixed.